# Google Sheets Script for Copying New data to the bottom row of existing data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am conducting a weekly export of data into Google Sheets. I need to stack the data week over week. I have the newly exported data in one worksheet, and the stacked data in another worksheet. I'm looking for a script that can take the new export, find the last row of the previous week's data, and paste the new data starting at that row.

None of my solutions have been close. What I envision is some sort of button that activates the script manually.